# Alamofire returns "The request timed out" with multipart image upload, but no problems with Postman

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, multipartform-data, postman

I am trying to POST data with an image using multipart upload with Alamofire. But it always returns "The request timed out" error. 
When tried the same web service with Postman, it works as it should.
Basically Alamofire keeps trying for sometime,and returns this error, but with Postman I can see that the response is almost immediate and no timeout is recieved.

Here is a the helper method I created for the post request:

```
     class func postRequestWithImage(image: UIImage, params : [String : String],success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (NSError) -> Void){

    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        let imageData : Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)!

        for (key, value) in params{
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image")


        }, to: WEBSERVICE_URL) { (encodingResult) in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    if response.result.isSuccess{
                        success(JSON(response.result.value!))
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }
                    else{
                        failure(response.result.error! as NSError)
                    }

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                failure(encodingError as NSError)
                print(encodingError)
            }

    }
}
```

The debug response for the same is:

```
    [Request]: http://website.com/v1/service/
    [Response]: nil
    [Data]: 0 bytes
    [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6080006441a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://website.com/v1/service/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://website.com/v1/service/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
    [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 510773039.719, "Initial Response Time": 510773051.183, "Request Completed Time": 510773120.615, "Serialization Completed Time": 510773120.615, "Latency": 11.464 secs, "Request Duration": 80.895 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 80.896 secs }
```

Comment: are you getting any kind of token in response?

Comment: @TusharSharma the above response is everything I get.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same bug with a sound upload, I have been stuck for a long time, the exact same code was working 2 month ago and stopped working at Alamofire update. I'm working on it, if I solve it I'll come back here to help

Comment: Hi @AlexyHody, I solved this. In my case there was a careless mistake. I used an extra slash in the url. I changed the web api to a different folder and while changing it in the iOS code I made this mistake.
I hope that helps you :)

Comment: I also had some changes made to the .htaccess file, so the request was not giving 404 error but instead trying to connect to that false address. errors that a beginner web developer will make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. In my case there was a careless mistake. I used an extra slash in the url. I changed the web api to a different folder and while changing it in the iOS code I made this mistake.

I also had some changes made to the .htaccess file, so the request was not giving 404 error but instead trying to connect to that false address. errors that a beginner web developer will make